# Meaning of 基本 X から Y メイン

Tags: meaning, expressions, particle-から

Talking about the Umeda branch of a hamburger chain, a Japanese colleague said:

> 梅田店は基本デリバリーからテイクアウトメインだよね。

So, does this branch do more deliveries than takeouts? Or the opposite?
Or mostly deliveries AND takeouts, rather than eating within the restaurant?

Comment: Also I don't know either main is delivery or take out. Perhaps deliveries and take outs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend was not comparing between デリバリー and テイクアウト. メイン is connected to "デリバリーからテイクアウト" as a whole, and the sentence says both デリバリー and テイクアウト are what they mostly do (as opposed to letting customers eat in the shop).

デリバリーからテイクアウト is short for デリバリーからテイクアウトまで, and in this case, it refers to almost the same thing as デリバリーやテイクアウト.

I also feel some Kansai people use から as a synonym for やら (e.g. 「AからBからCから、ようけあって、もうかなわんわ～」), but I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this enlightening answer! He is from Tokyo, actually, but might be using Kansai expressions sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

I think から creates a virtual spectrum from delivery to eating in, and your colleague is saying Umeda branch is mainly focused on the delivery to take out part of that spectrum.

Comment: So "デリバリーから" means "all forms of consumption, such as delivery"?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: It's just "delivery to take-out". It's a bit odd because you just have two values. It's more commonly used when there is actually a spectrum, for example "極左から中道メインで支持を集めた" (got support mainly from the radical left to centrists)